# Legalities of issuing beta app to client

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I am just about to issue my client with a beta version of my app and have come to adding their UDID to my provisioning profile so I can send it them and found this notice on the iOS Provisioning Portal:

> Your iOS Developer Program membership can be terminated if you provide
>   pre-release Apple Software to anyone other than employees,
>   contractors, and members of your organization who are registered as
>   Apple Developers and have a demonstrable need to know or use Apple
>   Software in order to develop and test applications on your behalf.
>   Unauthorized distribution of Apple Confidential Information (including
>   pre-release Apple Software) is prohibited and may subject you to both
>   civil and criminal liability.

Firstly, does my client HAVE to be an Apple Developer themself? Also, do I risk my licence by issuing it to them?

This legal wording seems very odd...

What does everyone else do?

Comment: I think that message is about Apple software - i.e. iOS betas etc. Not  your software.

Comment: In what way are you providing _"pre-release Apple Software"_ to anyone by giving them a beta version of your app?

Comment: Paul's right on the money here. You can release your own software to whoever you want to, it's only providing Apple's software to others that could cause you issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The clause restricts your ability to distribute Apple's software, not yours. It prevents you, for example, from giving iOS betas to all and sundry. It does not affect your ability to use provisioning profiles for distributing your own betas.

Answer (score 3):

> Firstly, does my client HAVE to be an Apple Developer themself?

No.  That's the purpose of the ad-hoc program.

> Also, do I risk my licence by issuing it to them?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Paul is right that this clause is about Apple's software. However note that Apple tends to reject your app if it thinks that it is in "beta", "debug" or "test" version: right in these days I had an application rejected only because it includes a "connection tester" that aims to test the server connection - well they thought it's some QA stuff and I had to explain them that it is not... All in all, you can send "beta" if it's fully functioning and without diagnostic features. Your other option is to send IPA (ad-hoc provisioning) to a limited number of devices avoiding Apple Store.